"Going to the movies is more fun ________" => with company, in company, or something else?

Even if I had a cheap ticket, I'd probably wait until I could go with friends. The whole experience is more fun with company.

I initially used with company for this sentence. However, I couldn't find many examples using it. Then, I found in company in the dictionary, but I'm still not sure if it's correct.
According to OD, in company means in a group of people.

With company is fine here. Another option is with friends, though that doesn’t do much to include family. Or there's with [or in, or even as part of] a group. Or even with others.

Thanks. So in company also works?

Maybe in company is a Britishism, since Oxford lists it but it sounds somewhat off to this American. There is the “compound preposition” in company with, but that’s something different (it means in the company of or together with). Then there’s also in polite company…

This may just be me, but as an American I think of "in company" as only being used for things that occur within a social interaction. You could use impolite language in mixed company, because the action is occurring "inside" the figurative circle of people, but the movie happens outside that circle so "in" feels weird. I have nothing to back this up though, so I could be wildly over hypothesizing.

The problem here is contextual and pragmatic. Generally, the expression with company is very formal. We just say: with friends or with other people.

TLDR: "in" is reasonable, but "with" is better here.
As Lambie says, this one example is very contextual. Beware of applying this to other contexts, because "in company" (or especially "in [adjective] company") is a very established phrase.
I think "with" works here just because "It's more fun with" is a common pattern (like the dairy advertising slogan "It's better with butter!").
It could feel even more natural with an added modifier, like "it's more fun with some company." It's common enough to go without it—"I'm lonely; I want company"—but it's also common to throw one in: "You look sad; do you want any company?" Also note, "company" with no modifier can have a totally unrelated meaning about houseguests: "Clean up your room, we're having company coming over."

Do you find "with company" or "with some company" too formal?

@AnIELTSLearner It's not formal at all, especially not "some company" or "a little company." I've said sentences much like your proposed one when I was single but would still buy two tickets to a concert and take a friend.
